# Formulae or logic to find and combine values from two different tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am a newbie to excel and I need your help in understanding how I can find a solution to this problem.

Problem:
I have two tables.

Table 1:
[image]

Table 1:
The top row shows the machinery names, 2nd row shows which week the machinery is scheduled for production. The table below that shows what all are the part IDs and how many are in stock. The space in green shows the count relative to the part needed for creating a machinery. Eg: in the first row, Part A required to create VAB machine is 6 and since we have 8 available in stock the value displayed is 6 as that is the only count required to create a machine for that week. Now when we look at week 32, the count is shown as -6 because the part is already consumed during previous weeks and is out of stock.

Table 2:
[image]

Table 2:
This table shows the count of parts ordered and which week the part will arrive.

My problem is, I need to find a way where in if the part is stock out, then excel should check the second table and see if the part is ordered and if yes, check which week its arriving and based on that update the values in table 1 green space.

eg: in table 1, you can see part A is stock out from week 31. But, in table 2 you can see new set of parts will arrive on week 32. Now the table should be automatically updated so that from week 32 we have new stock for part A and both week 32 and 33 should be 6 instead of -6.

Hope you understood my problem. Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: How do I now how many parts are needed for a specific machine? Of course, you mentioned that in this case it will be 6; but this does not allow to set up a proper procedure if this information is missing?

Comment: Adding to @karl, table 2 shows inflows but table 1 (as stated by you) appears to be both outflows AND net balance. One possibility is to capture your outflows somewhere else (possibly in table 2 as negative amounts), then your table 1 becomes the net balance table (which can be built with formulas only, instead of a mixture of formulas and data). But if you further alter your table 2 I see you being able to possibly replace table 1 with a pivot table. Good luck.